# Custom Listview not binding

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i am trying to bind a custom list view in my app from sqlite database. Data fetched from db successfully and activity execute without any error but displaying blankactivity . Here is the code please suggest where is the issue and how to fix it? 
 This is display adapter

```
package com.example.automaticprofilechanger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> id;
private ArrayList<String> profile_Name;
private ArrayList<String> profile;
private ArrayList<String> time;


public DisplayAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> id,ArrayList<String> Profile_Name, ArrayList<String> Profile, ArrayList<String> Time) {
    this.mContext = c;
    this.id = id;
    this.profile_Name = Profile_Name;
    this.profile = Profile;
    this.time = Time;
}

public int getCount() {

    return id.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder mHolder;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    if (child == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listcell, null);

        mHolder = new Holder();
        mHolder.txt_Profile_Name = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_Profile_Name);
        mHolder.txt_Profile = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_Profile);
        mHolder.txt_Time = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_Time);

        child.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
    }
    mHolder.txt_Profile_Name.setText(profile_Name.get(pos));
    mHolder.txt_Profile.setText(profile.get(pos));
    mHolder.txt_Time.setText(time.get(pos));
    return child;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView txt_Profile_Name;
    TextView txt_Profile;
    TextView txt_Time;
}
```

}

Here is the Code  where using Display Adapter

```
private void displayData() {
    List<Time> obj= db.getAllTime();

    for (Time time : obj) {
        _Profile_Name.add(time._profilename);
        _profile.add(time._profile);
        _Time.add(time._time);
    }
    DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(ListTimeActivity.this,_id,_Profile_Name, _profile,_Time);
    list.setAdapter(disadpt);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: your `getItem` returns null

Comment: What does _id contain when you instantiate the adapter? getCount() returns id.size() so if that arraylist is empty, your list will show no rows. I suspect Digvesh may be correct if you could confirm.

Comment: @NigelK id.size() is 0

Comment: Well that is it (or at least part of the problem). Make sure getCount() returns the size of the dataset your listview represents. Please refer to the answer from Digvesh.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getCount() {

    return profile_Name.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments

> id.size() is 0

So its natural you don't see the list populated by data.

You need to make sure you add items to arraylist id before passing it to the constructor of adapter class

You are returning null in `getItem`

```
   @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return id.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    return id.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }
```

Comment: @Supreet are you sure your list is populated?

Comment: While debugging the code getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) never fires

Comment: @Supreet your code looks fine. post the relevant parts of the code here itself by editing your post

Comment: @Supreet id is 0 meanining id is not populated. have you populated id before passing it to the constructor of adapter class